# openshift client tools for windows, rhc setup error

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

```
C:\files\ruby>rhc setup --debug
DEBUG: Using config file C:/Users/files/.openshift/express.conf
DEBUG: Running greeting_stage
OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace,
and check that other programs like Git are properly installed.
DEBUG: Running login_stage
DEBUG: Connecting to https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG: Client supports API versions 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG: Created new httpclient
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG:    code 200 3167 ms
DEBUG: Server supports API versions 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7
DEBUG:    Using API version 1.7
DEBUG: Client API version 1.7 is not current. Refetching API
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api
DEBUG:    code 200  392 ms
DEBUG: Getting user info
DEBUG: Request GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/user
DEBUG: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I see the error `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` when i try to run `rhc setup` from my command prompt in windows vista

Also not sure whether this is important but there is no such file `C:/Users/files/.openshift/express.conf`

Thanks

Comment: Could you fix the issue? I'm getting the same error on Ubuntu!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the httpclient gem version 2.4.0 is not working with the wizard, you have to uninstall it and install the version 2.3.4.1

Comment: This is mostly true, if you have an existing ~/.openshift/express.conf, then 2.4.0 works fine, if it is a new install of rhc and you don't have a ~/.openshift/express.conf, then rhc setup will fail with the above error

Comment: How can I unistall the 2.4.0 httpclient gem version and install the 2.3.4.1 in Ubuntu?

Comment: thanks, worked for me too: `sudo gem uninstall httpclient` then `sudo gem install httpclient -v 2.3.4.1` on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for Ubuntu it worked for me:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall rhc
$ sudo gem uninstall httpclient
$ sudo gem install httpclient -v 2.3.4
$ sudo gem install rhc
$ rhc setup
```