# RHC not working on OpenShift instance

Tags: rubygems, openshift, redhat, openshift-client-tools

I am just getting started with Node, so I created an instance on OpenShift and am trying to install rhc so that I can setup aliases for my domain name.

I ran the following and the installation was successful for rhc (1.25.2).

```
gem install rhc
```

The next step was to run:

```
rhc setup
```

However, I'm getting the error

```
bash: rhc: command not found
```

Help would be appreciated.  Ultimately, the problem I am trying to fix is stopping my website from redirecting http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com/app

--

Update:

I found rhc located in /var/lib/openshift/[MYUSERDIR]/.gem/bin and I tried to run the setup and I ended up with this message:

```
./rhc setup
OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace, and     check that other programs like Git are properly installed.

An unexpected error occured: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Update 2:

rhc setup now runs, but fails when attempting to generate a token:

```
Generate a token now? (yes|no) yes
Generating an authorization token for this client ... /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /var/lib/openshift/[hidden]/.openshift (Errno::EACCES)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with node.js

Comment: You should log a ticket at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online and then delete this question

Comment: I solved that problem using [the following solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24110237/697630).

Comment: The command now works, however rhc setup results in a no permissions error on attempting to generate a token.

Comment: @Leon got the same problem, did you fix this?